# Name duplication

Tags: support, user-accounts

Is it possible for two users to have the exact same username?

In particular, I look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/27199/richard-simson) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/27326/richard-simson).

I don't like that, I think. Another mixedmath prancing around... hmm. Is there any limit to the number of mixedmaths running around?

Comment: Yes, it is quite possible. Trust me, there are more Alex's around than I can count, which is one reason I changed my username name to my full name.

Comment: Another [mixedmath](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/27342/)... Very confusing!

Comment: Note that those two are both "Unregistered accounts" of recent creation. Morevoer, from the beginning of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/122795/742) it is clear that it is the *same* user.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that he was the same user. But that's how I noticed.

Comment: In the real world there are many collections of people who share a name. We distinguish the individuals by context and/or appearance. People can distinguish you as the mixedmath with the blue picture.

Comment: @Jay: Unfortunately, you cannot distinguish between people by their pictures or rep by simply looking at their name after they comment. This also makes me wonder how pinging works if there are two people with the same name who have both commented. That's very unclear to me.

Comment: There's a bunch of Matts, Jonases, and Davids as well, so I suppose duplication's par for the course.

Answer (score 3):

There is no limit. Users are fundamentally differentiated by their numeric user id, so anyone is free to use any name they choose (within reason - names that are obviously offensive would be edited, for example).